# How can I access an object declared in the AppDelegate class from my view controller class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

This is my `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    ProductHandlerModel *handler;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

-(ProductHandlerModel*)getHandler;

@end
```

and this is in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     handler = [[ProductHandlerModel alloc]init];
     return YES;
}

- (ProductHandlerModel*)getHandler {
     return handler;
}
```

How can I access this handler object from another `UIViewController` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call like

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate getHandler];
```

or simply call like

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] getHandler];
```

Dont forget to import.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: Also it is handy to move this code to class method, like +(AppDelegate *)sharedInstance, just to avoid writing this line again. But I need to mention that generally it's a bad practice to store something in your appdelegate like this, but sometimes it makes sense of course.